# I have a lot of images for my website. However, they all need to be cropped. Is there a way using graphics magick?

Tags: images, graphics

I have about 4000 images that need to be cropped. The task is rather simple really. They all have a white border that ***varies*** but is always between say 20 and 50 pixels. I want to use graphics magick to remove that white border from all the images. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GraphicsMagick `-trim` operator **[here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-trim)**. Does what I need. Thanks for the other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a php script that crops all of the images.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: This suffers the same issue as the above (only crops fixed sized borders).

Answer (score 0):

You can [batch crop & resize images](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_eEKD8AJz0) with the [free IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) tool

Comment: Unfortunately the borders on the images *vary*. I can't tell **IfranView** to just crop all images by 20 px on each side. That would crop some of the content of some of my images.